# How to calculate a posterior probability with a given Gaussian Mixture Model?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, notation, matlab, machine-learning

I'm building a GMM-based classifier in speech processing and I'm using GMM as a probabilistic scoring mechanism (therefore I don't intrinsically care about the underlying mixture components). For example, I have two classes of speech, neutral and stressed, each has its own trained GMM, and I classify an unknown speech by scoring its feature with the GMMs of the two classes and comparing the results against some decision threshold.

I already have an open-source EM/GMM matlab code to train my model (therefore I have the GMM parameters), but I don't know how exactly I'm supposed to calculate a posterior probability based on it.

I've also found [the equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZmY9.png) I need (from [this paper](https://www.ll.mit.edu/mission/cybersec/publications/publication-files/full_papers/0802_Reynolds_Biometrics-GMM.pdf)), but I'm having a hard time translating it into matlab code (too bad my math has gotten rusty):

1. In the second equation, what do the sigma notations mean? First one=square root of the determinant of the ith covariance matrix? Second one=summing from i to -1 of observation vector minus ith mean vector?
2. What does (2*pi)^(D/2) mean? raising 2pi to the power of (D/2)? what if D is odd?

I wrote a silly matlab function of what I did so far:

```
function prob =GMMposterior(x,mu,covmat,weights)
% inputs: x, Dx1 observation vector;
%         mu, Dxn mean vector (n is the number of components)
%         covmat, DxDxn covariance matrix; 
%         weights, 1xn component weights. 

% output: prob, a posterior probability

d=size(x,1); % get the number of dimensions
w=size(weights,2); % get the number of compoments/weights
g=zeros(w,1);
for i=1:w
    g(i)=exp(-1/2*(x-mu(:,i))'/???)/((2*pi)^(round?(d/2)*sqrt?(det(covmat(:,:,i)));
end

prob=weights*g;
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First: Yes, the square root of the determinant of the $i$-th covariance matrix. Second: No, the inverse of the $i$-th covariance matrix.
2. Yes, raising $2\pi$ to the $D/2$-th power. If $D$ is odd, this is a half integer; you still need to use $D/2$, without the rounding suggested in your code. $x^{D/2}=\sqrt{x^D}$.

Comment: Thanks...my questions seem kind of silly now.
I changed the one-liner in the loop to `g(i)=exp(-1/2*(x-mu(:,i))'/covmat(:,:,i)*(x-mu(:,i)))/((2*pi)^(d/2)*sqrt(det(covmat(:,:,i))));` does that look alright? (matlab suggests me to use b/A instead of b*inv(A))

Comment: @ladiesman: I'm afraid I don't speak matlab :-) It doesn't look right to me, because an inverse matrix can be multiplied to a vector from either side, whereas this division notation only works from one side, so I don't see how matlab would know, if $b$ were a square matrix, from which side you want to multiply it by the inverse. Having said that, I can't exclude the possibility that this is how it's done in matlab, that it will figure it all out by itself from the dimensions, and it will work :-)

Comment: as per matlab's suggestion, "'inv' is slow and inaccurate; use A\b for inv(A)*b, and b/A for b*inv(A)". Other than this implementation detail, does my function look valid (it's giving me results :) ? thanks again!

Comment: @ladiesman: Ah, cunning. That makes a lot of sense, since it's better to solve the system of equations for a single vector than to compute the inverse. Yes other than that it looks right to me.